Cost-efficiency of updating specific document fields vs whole documents in Cloud Firestore
I am developing a UIKit app using Firebase as a BaaS.
Please consider the following scenario: a user wants to change their username and I have a document in Firestore for their profile, e.g. a document that contains fields for the user's username and email.
Is there any official piece of documentation that confirms whether it would be more expensive to re-save the whole document from the client, merging it with the existing one, if any, than to update the username field specifically?
The reason I want to know this is that in my specific implementation it would be more convenient for me to let Firestore do the merging.
Here is a swift sample in case it makes my question clearer:
class DatabaseController {
    let db: Firestore
    let authController: AuthControllerProtocol
        
    init(
        db: Firestore = .firestore(),
        authController: AuthControllerProtocol
    ) {
        self.db = db
        self.authController = authController
    }
    
    // first function: save the whole document each time, merging it with the existing one, if any
    func save(_ profile: Profile) async {
        guard let currentUserUid = authController.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            print(">> \(Self.self).\(#function): could not find currentUserUid")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let encodedProfile = try Firestore.Encoder().encode(profile)
            do {
                try await db.collection("users").document(currentUserUid).setData(encodedProfile, merge: true)
            } catch {
                print(">> \(Self.self).\(#function): could not update profile: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        } catch {
            print(">> \(Self.self).\(#function): could not encode profile: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // second function: only update the specific field that you know should be updated
    func save(_ username: String) async {
        guard let currentUserUid = authController.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            print(">> \(Self.self).\(#function): could not find currentUserUid")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try await db.collection("collection").document("\(currentUserUid)").setData(["key": username], merge: true)
        } catch {
            print(">> \(Self.self).\(#function): could not update username: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
}


To be fair, it always helps the reader of a question to know why the question is being asked.  If you don't share the purpose for asking the question, you might never know if any given answer is going to be helpful.  But you really should be clear what you mean by "more expensive".  Are you talking about money or performance or something else?

@DougStevenson Okay, I guess I was mislead by the seemingly irrelevant questions that I've received in the past and seen under other people's posts. For sure I wasn't expecting Doug Stevenson to do the questions. By the way yes, I'm talking about money: I would like to know if Firebase has confirmed whether setting the fields of a Firestore document charges you less (money) than setting the whole document each time and letting Firestore do the merging. The reason I want to know this is that in my specific implementation it would be more convenient for me to let Firestore do the merging

All of that information should be in the question itself (and not buried in comments) in order to help future readers understand the question.

The price for writing a document is the same, no matter how many fields you write. Since you're not charged for incoming bandwidth, that won't make a difference either. And if the stored document ends up being the same between these approaches, the storage cost will also be the same.
For full details on the pricing for Firestore, see: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing.

Okay right because the documentation says "You are charged for the network bandwidth used by your Firestore requests, as shown in the following sections. The network bandwidth cost of a Firestore request depends on the request’s response size, the location of your Firestore database, and the destination of the response."

That talks only about the response data of your requests, not the inbound bandwidth. In the same section where you got that quote from, it says: "Inbound data transfer: Free".  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Right I should have just quoted those 4 words, thank you very much
